# Symfony2 Custom Repository Not Working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've followed every step in the book, but I can't get to work any entity custom repository.

For example, I have my User entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table("fos_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="XXX\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser implements ParticipantInterface
{
}
```

And it repository class:

```
namespace XXX\UserBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * UserRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function initializeUser()
    {
        //some logic
    }

}
```

But when I call $user->initializeUser(); I get **Fatal error: Call to undefined method XXX\UserBundle\Entity\User::initializeUser()**, so it's clear that it doesn't recognize the custom repository, even though I've declared it on entity class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The custom repository does not add a method to the Entity object.

To call your custom method, with `$em` the entity manager:

```
$em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->initializeUser(),
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been missing that part.